# How to aggregate PAPI uncore events such as skx_unc_imc0 to measure for all devices?

Tags: perf, papi

PAPI counts events per device (which can be iMC, caching and home agent(cha)). These are counted as separate events such as skx_unc_imc0::UNC_M_RPQ_OCCUPANCY for iMC 0. Is there a way to measure this for all the iMCs at the same time?
The Linux perf tool can do this, an equivalent event is unc_m_rpq_occupancy, but this cannot be measured from PAPI.

Comment: If there's no way to do it from PAPI, I'd guess that `perf` does it manually, by counting the event for each IMC, and summing them itself.  That would make some sense, keeping the kernel API simple when user-space can get get accurate counts by doing the work itself.